# In $\Delta ABC$, $AB = 14, BC = 16, AC = 26$. $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $D$ is the point on $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, congruences-geometry

> In $\Delta ABC$, $AB = 14, BC = 16, AC = 26$. $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $D$ is the point on $BC$ such that $AD$ bisects $\angle BAC$. Let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $B$ to $AD$ . Find $PM$ .

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

The first thing which I noticed is that, $AC \parallel PM$ from Geogebra. I tried everything to prove that from the diagram but without success. I got no idea as I don't think checking for areas will help, and I tried angle-chasing to the most. And obviously, I am in $50$ steps away from solving the problem.

Can someone show me how $AC \parallel PM$ ? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ is the midpoint of $BK$. $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

So $\triangle BPM \sim \triangle BKC$ (by A-S-S).

$KC = AC - AK = 26 - 14 = 12$

So $PM = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

PM||AC because it connects midpoints of BC and BK.P is mid point of BK, do you know why?

Comment: Oh got it, Midpoint Theorem .

Answer (score 1):

All the side length $a,b,c$ are known,
hence, we can get all the angles $\alpha,\ \beta,\ \gamma$;

$|BM|=\tfrac12\,a$,

$|BP|$ can be found from $\triangle ABP$,

$\angle PBM=\tfrac12\,\alpha+\beta-90^\circ$,

use the cosine rule for $\triangle BMP$ to find $|MP|$:

\begin{align} 
|MP|^2=|BM|^2+|BP|^2-2\cdot|BM|\cdot|BP|\cdot\cos\angle PBM
.
\end{align}